# Flutter - Bottom Sheet height transition

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

for my flutter project I need to create an animated bottom sheet in the sense that it will transition height when pressing a button... How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched some flutter package because of like your reason.
I think that 'sliding_up_panel' package is what you find.
https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel